# Convert this Windsor snippet to StructureMap for NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dependency-injection, structuremap

Can someone help me convert the below to StructureMap?

```
public class NHibernateInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
                               .UsingFactoryMethod(k => BuildSessionFactory()));

        container.Register(Component.For<NHibernateSessionModule>());

        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactoryProvider>().AsFactory());

        container.Register(Component.For<IEnumerable<ISessionFactory>>()
                                    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.ResolveAll<ISessionFactory>()));

        HttpContext.Current.Application[SessionFactoryProvider.Key]
                        = container.Resolve<ISessionFactoryProvider>();
    }

    #endregion
    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory() { ... }
}
```

I have this thus far in my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    IContainer container = new Container(
        x =>
        {
            x.For<ISessionFactory>().Use  // ??? NHibernateHelper.BuildSessionFactory();

            x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use<StructureMapControllerActivator>();
            x.For<IBar>().Use<Bar>();
        }
    );


    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructuredMapDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

1. NHibernateHelper.BuildSessionFactory() is my method, not sure how to set that up for ISessionFactory.
2. Not sure why I need to put NHibernateSessionModule in my container, I just wired up the module in web.config, isn't that enough?
3. I don't understand the rest, like how is ISessionFactoryProvider being wired up as ".AsFactory()", don't you need to provide the implementation there?
4. resolveAll is doing what?

I'm new to StructureMap (and DI in general) so please don't assume I know much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a typical setup that I have used for wiring up StructureMap and NHibernate:

```
IContainer container = new Container(c => 
{
    c.Scan(s=>
    {
        // This autoregisters the IFoo to Foo
        s.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
        s.WithDefaultConventions();
    };

    // SessionFactory needs to be a singleton object
    c.ForSingletonOf<ISessionFactory>()
        .Use(NHibernateHelper.BuildSessionFactory());

    // Add your own interceptor implementation here
    c.For<IInterceptor>().Use<EmptyInterceptor>();

    // I assume that NHibernateSession uses the NHibernateSessionModule
    // I use a similar implementation named TransactionBoundaryModule 
    c.For<INHibernateSession>()
        .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
        .Use<NHibernateSession>();

    // Gets the current session from the NHibernateSession
    // Ensures one session per request
    c.For<ISession>().Use(x =>
    {
        var instance = x.GetInstance<INHibernateSession>();
        return instance.CurrentSession;
    });

    // Same for StatelessSession
    c.For<IStatelessSession>()
        .Use(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>()
        .OpenStatelessSession());
};
```

FYI...I have a reference implementation at https://github.com/codeprogression/Fluently-Persistent. Start with CP.FluentlyPersistent.Web/Global.asax.cs and follow it through. I use a StructureMap `Registry` class to wire up NHibernate, but the syntax is very similar.

---

UPDATE (to answer your comment/question on the lines in the NHibernateInstaller class):

The short answer is remove the class - it is not needed once you provide an implementation of the ISessionFactoryProvider named SessionFactoryProvider.  Add this line: `HttpContext.Current.Application[SessionFactoryProvider.Key] = container.GetInstance<ISessionFactoryProvider>();` to your global.asax.cs.

Here is why...In StructureMap, with assembly scanning, it is not necessary to register NHibernateSessionModule. The current SM binaries don't include the typed-factory implementation that Windsor has, but an implementation is in the GitHub source (look for AutoFactory). To get around this limitation, you must create an derivation of ISessionFactoryProvider called SessionFactoryProvider with the GetSessionFactories() method.

Comment: very nice, btw, what do you use stateless session for?  is that for read-only objects for performance reasons?

Comment: the article is here: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx

Comment: Yep, I use stateless session for bulk data operations - when I won't be retrieving/saving the same object repeatedly, so NH doesn't have to maintain it in first level cache. Performance is between regular NH and straight ADO.  See here: http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/10/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernates-stateless-sessions/

Comment: I do like the lazy initialization - I need to explore that approach.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how I can convert this code: `container.Register(Component.For<NHibernateSessionModule>());
container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactoryProvider>().AsFactory());
container.Register(Component.For<IEnumerable<ISessionFactory>>()
                                    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.ResolveAll<ISessionFactory>()));`

Comment: "the short answer is remove the class", which class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3512/discussion-between-richard-cirerol-and-blankman)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. You can remove the NHibernateInstaller class - it is a Windsor implementation similar to StructureMap's Registry class.  You can provide an implementation of ISessionFactoryProvider and add the provider to the application context.